# Male analogous of ancilla

Tags: word-request

I recall my Latin professor mentioning during a class that there was a male counterpart for **ancilla**, but he didn't remember the exact word at that moment. It seemed obvious that there *was* a word, since he ruled out words like **servus** for being too unspecific. It also seems that the word does not come [regularly at least] from the same root, since it would have been easier to recall.

**Q: What could that word be?** I can't tell if the word came from a specific era of Latin, but it was probably classical or post-classical, judging from my professor's background (or maybe ecclesiastical?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latin had a number of words for servants or slaves. Perhaps you are thinking of *[famulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfamulus1),* which has a feminine form *famula* with a similar meaning to *ancilla.*

By the way, Lewis and Short indicates that *servus* and *[ancilla](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=ancilla)* were in fact parallel in at least some cases:

> maidservant, handmaid, female slave (com. used as fem. of servus, instead of serva).

I don’t therefore think there actually is any one single male counterpart to *ancilla*.

Comment: Famulus makes me think of "**fa**muli tuorum", the fourth line of the hymn in honor of John the Baptist that starts with [Ut quaeant laxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ut_queant_laxis).

Comment: This hymn is the basis of our do-re-mi system. Original **ut** was replaced by **do**.

Comment: In my highschool textbook (around age 12), *ancilla* and *servus* were indeed treated as aequivalents, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: In LLPSI, Ørberg also uses _servus_ and _ancilla_ as equivalents.